# Is there a way to add a header above the amsart header (an image)

Tags: graphics, header-footer, fancyhdr, amsart

So in amsart, there is a header by default but I would like another "header" above this one so that I can place an image in the upper-right hand corner of every page. I'd also like the option to do this with the footer, too. But the package fancyhdr conflicts with the existing header/footer for amsart:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\rhead{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}

\lfoot{This is Document ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO}

\begin{document}

\title{This is the title for Document ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

As you can see, everything is overlapping in the header/footer. I would like the image to be more upper right (but not touching the corner) and would like the lower left footer to be more lower left (but not touching the corner).

Comment: The overlap is caused by trying to fit a graphic that is about 305pt high into the 8pt of space (`\headheight`) reserved for the header.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/IslCJiK.png)?

Comment: @alwaysask Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with some values for you to tweak the desired placement/size:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%
%\rhead{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\rhead{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(40,25){\includegraphics[height=15mm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{picture}}

\lfoot{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-100,-50){\includegraphics[height=15mm]{example-image-b}}
    \end{picture}
    This is Document ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO}

\begin{document}

    \title{This is the title for Document ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO}
    \maketitle

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```